# Ereshamann Connection on Sphere's Frame Bundle

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, spheres, connections, principal-bundles

In order to better understand connections on principal bundles, I would like to compute the Ereshmann distribution (horizontal distribution) and the connection 1-form associated on the frame bundle of $S^2$, explicitly in coordinates. But I am stuck!

I did the following:

I took the coordinates for $S^2$: given $$U=\Big\{ (\phi,\theta ): \theta \in [0,2\pi) , \phi \in \Big]0 ,\pi[ \Big[   \Big\}$$
I took $\varphi: U \to S^2$ defined by $\varphi(\phi, \theta)= \big(r \cos(\theta ) \sin(\phi) , r \sin(\theta)\sin (\phi) , r \cos(\phi)\big)$  The metric is given by $$g_{\phi,\theta}(\phi,\theta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
r^2 & 0\\
0  &  r^2\sin (\phi)^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and an orthonormal basis by $$e_{\phi}:= \frac{1}{r}\partial_{\phi}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  e_{\theta}:=\frac{1}{r \sin(\phi)}\partial_{\theta}   $$  The dual basis is then $e_{\phi}^*:=  r d \phi ,e_{\theta}^*:= r \sin(\phi)d\theta  $. I used the first Cartan equation to compute the connection matrix (on $S^2$) in local coordinates. The first Cartan equation gives$$
\begin{cases}
de_{\phi}^*=-\omega_{1}^{1} \wedge e_{\phi}^* -\omega_{2}^1 \wedge e_{\theta}^* \\
de_{\theta}^* =-\omega_{1}^{2} \wedge e_{\phi}^*-  \omega_{2}^{2} \wedge e_{\theta}^*
\end{cases}
$$
For a Levi Civita connection we have  $\omega_{1}^{1}=\omega_{2}^{2}=0$ e $\omega_{1}^{2}=-\omega_{2}^{1}$ then if  $\omega^{1}_{2}=a_{\phi }d\phi +a_{\theta}d\theta $ we obtain

$$
\begin{cases}
d \big(r d \phi \big)= - \big( a_{\phi }d\phi +a_{\theta}d\theta  \big) \wedge \Big( r\sin(\phi)d\theta \Big) \\ 
d\big( r\sin(\phi)d\theta  \big) = \big(a_{\phi}d\phi +a_{\theta}d\theta \big)\wedge 
\Big( r d \phi \Big) 
\end{cases}
$$  that is $$
\begin{cases}
0 = -  a_{\phi } r\sin(\phi)d\phi \wedge   d\theta   \\ 
 r\cos(\phi)d\phi \wedge d\theta  = a_{\theta} r d\theta  \wedge 
d \phi
\end{cases}
$$  then $a_{\phi }=0 ,a_{\theta}   = -\cos(\phi)$ thus$$\omega^{1}_{2}= -\cos(\phi) d\theta $$

I'm quite sure the computation is correct (I've computed the Gaussian curvature!). Let's now consider the frame bundle $GL(2, \mathbb{R} ) \to \text{Fr}(TS^2)$. From the connection matrix I've computed, it should be possible to compute the connection 1-form $\omega$  on $\text{Fr}(TS^2)$ with values in $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and from that one the horizontal distribution by imposing the equations for $X$ given by $\omega(X)=0$. I read as much books and notes as possible on that thing, but I still don't understand how to get $\omega$!

The best reference I've found is  "Differential geometry" by Loring W. Tu.

Comment: Why should the frame bundle be a principal $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ bundle?

Comment: "Heuristically", because you can identify any frame with the invertible matrix that send the coordinates frame to the one you have

Comment: The tangent spaces are two dimensional, not 4 dimensional

Comment: You're right, sorry, is $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ (I was thinking about its dimension by writing)